# What is the purpose of converters in jsf?

Tags: jsf, converters

It appears that a converter usually has two methods `getAsObject()` and `getAsString()`, which will convert Object into or from strings.

Why do we need to do this?

For example, in `dataTable` we can always bind an object with `var`. Why can't we do similar things here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end the client (usually a browser) will receive a rendered version of your JSF Component tree, which you usually built via .xhtml files.

The browser doesn't know about `BigDecimals` or `Dates` for example. If you write "1.003" in an input field of a form, how should the browser know whether it will be a `String`, or a `float` or a `BigDecimal` on server side? It cannot know that  and also couldn't handle that. Thus the communication between server and browser is always via `Strings`. When the HTML gets rendered, the `getAsString()` method will be used. When processing the transmitted form inputs, JSF will use the `getAsObject()` to convert it back to the real type.

Why does `var` work in dataTables? Because here you will only go "one way". A dataTable will only display something and thus the generic `toString()` method can be used. A conversion to the Object isn't necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I will copy and paste a great answer for [balusc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) about why we should use a JSF converter(i do not remember the link of question itself)

JSF generates HTML. HTML is in Java terms basically one large String. To represent Java objects in HTML, they have to be converted to String. Also, when a HTML form is submitted, the submitted values are treated as String in the HTTP request parameters. Under the covers, JSF extracts them from the `HttpServletRequest#getParameter()` which returns String.To convert between a non-standard Java object (i.e. not a String, Number or Boolean for which EL has built-in conversions)
you have to supply a custom Converter for your Entity class.This Converter implements two methods   `getAsString()` method so that the desired Java Object is been represented in an unique string representation and `getAsObject()` method so that the HTTP request parameter can be converted back to the desired Java Object